# Configure UPower to recognize PowerWare 9130 UPS (Ubuntu Xenial)

Tags: ubuntu, configure, ups

I just installed Ubuntu Xenial Desktop (16.04.1) on my HP ProDesk 600 G2 and there is a red (empty) battery icon at the upper right. The PC is plugged into a UPS which I know works (Powerware 9130) and it is fully charged. upower --enumerate shows

> /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/ups_hiddev0

...connected by USB, obviously.

How do I configure UPower or anything else required to properly recognize the UPS? Is there a UPS description file I need to put in somewhere? Or a package of UPS definitions?